# AngularJS: How to update view when model changed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Consider this `HTML` form

```
 <form name="form" class="form-horizontal" novalidate>
     <div class="form-group">
         <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Template</label>

             <div class="col-lg-4">
                 <label>
                     <select class="form-control"
                             data-ng-model="templateSelected"
                             data-ng-options="transactionTemplate.name for transactionTemplate in transactionTemplates">
                     </select>
                 </label>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
             <label class="col-lg-2 control-label"
                    for="transactionName">Name</label>

             <div class="col-lg-4">
                 <input type="text" name="transactionName"
                        class="form-control"
                        id="transactionName"
                        placeholder="Transaction Name"
                        data-ng-model="transaction.name" required>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
             <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Type</label>

             <div class="btn-group col-lg-3" data-toggle="buttons"
                  data-ng-model="transaction.debit" required>
                 <label class="btn btn-default"
                        data-ng-click="setDebitTransaction('true')">
                      <input type="radio">
                      Debit
                 </label>
                 <label class="btn btn-default"
                        data-ng-click="setDebitTransaction('false')">
                     <input type="radio">
                     Credit
                 </label>
             </div>

         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
             <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Date</label>

             <datepicker data-ng-model="transaction.date"></datepicker>
         </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Amount</label>

                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="input-append">
                            <!-- to be added later -->
                            <!--button type="button" class="btn" ng-model="buttonSelect.currency" bs-button-select="['$', '₹']"></button-->
                            <!--suppress HtmlFormInputWithoutLabel -->
                            <input type="text" name="transactionAmount"
                                   class="form-control"
                                   data-ng-model="transaction.amount" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Category</label>

                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <label>
                            <select data-ng-model="transaction.category"
                                    class="form-control"
                                    data-ng-options="category.name group by category.parent for category in categories"
                                    required>
                            </select>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="controls button-group col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-2">
                        <button type="submit"
                                class="btn btn-danger"
                                data-ng-disabled="form.$invalid"
                                data-ng-click="saveTransaction()">
                            Submit
                        </button>
                        <button type="submit"
                                class="btn btn-link"
                                data-ng-click="resetTransactionForm()">
                            Cancel
                        </button>
           </div>
      </div>
</form>
```

I want to update the `HTML` elements when my model `transaction` changes
This is my `Controller`

```
$scope.$watch('templateSelected', function () {
    if ($scope.templateSelected !== undefined) {
        console.log('selected transaction template:', $scope.templateSelected);
        $scope.transaction.name = $scope.templateSelected.name;
        $scope.transaction.debit = $scope.templateSelected.debit;
        $scope.transaction.category = $scope.templateSelected.category;
    }
}, true);
```

All I see is that when `templateSelected` has valid value and `$watch` is executed, only `name` value is updated/visible on `HTML` form and not the

```
        $scope.transaction.debit = $scope.templateSelected.debit;
        $scope.transaction.category = $scope.templateSelected.category;
```

What am I missing here? What do I need to do to display these values as well?

**UPDATED**

Created [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/IbMsP6D0WP9IERt0o8ci?p=preview)

Comment: Can you make a plunket?

Comment: Hi, I have created one

Comment: Your plunker has no Angular script defined. Include it and fix the upcoming digest errors

Comment: @daydreamer: But you didn't update the link to it ? It stell does not work !